# systemd-nspawn container failed with error code 1 on copy of Linux filesystem

Tags: linux, systemd

I am attempting to use systemd-nspawn on a full copy of a Linux filesystem:

I tared up my filesystem, exlcuding /opt:

```
cd /
tar -cvpzf /opt/test/rootfs.tar --exclude=/opt/ --one-file-system /
```

I untared it under /opt/test/:

```
cd /tar/test/
tar -xvf rootfs.tar
```

When I try systemd-nspawn on it, I get the following error:

```
root@testbox:/opt/test# systemd-nspawn -D .
Spawning container test on /opt/test.
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
Container test failed with error code 1.
```

Any suggestions? Or is there a way for me to get more detailed about this error?

Comment: also seen at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close/163560

Answer (score 0):

Installing `systemd` and `dbus` inside of the container worked for me.